# ViewBag select lists datetime to date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, selectlist, viewbag

In my controller -

```
ViewBag.DatesEnum = new SelectList(_db.blah.Where(w => w.Active == true).AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Date");
```

In view -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.blahDate, (SelectList)ViewBag.DatesEnum)
```

Ofc it's a datetime value being passed in and I was wondering how best to convert it to a ToShortDateString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ViewBag.DatesEnum = _db.blah.Where(w => w.Active == true)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(i => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Value = i.ID,
                                            Text = i.Date.ToShortDateString()
                                        });
```

Then you can display dropdown in your view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.blahDate, 
                           (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DatesEnum)
```

It would be better if you add dropdown data to your model and skip using ViewBag.